# FINDSTR: Created An Undeletable File - Need Help Deleting It

Tags: batch-file, delete-file

**The Problem**: I was messing around with Batch files and wanted to use multiple colors. I found a solution on Stack Overflow however, I accidentally created a file that is un deletable. It takes up 0kb, has no data in it, its file type is "file", and apparently it is constantly being used by Desktop even though no tasks are running

You can view the code below...

**WARNING The code below will create an undeletable file named Immortal**

```
@echo off
:StartScreen
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
  set "DEL=%%a"
)

cls
call :ColorText 08 "Immortal : File"

pause >nul
:ColorText
echo off
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1
```

**Attempted Solutions**: I looked online for possible solutions and got some other people to help to. We did a virus check, disk error check, and even booted it in safe mode to try and delete it. Also we have all admin privileges on the file and even used an elevated command prompt to delete the file but nothing works! It is almost as if the file exists but doesn't exist at the same time.

Comment: Despite your question being a repost and not being about a programming issue; are you expecting our members to go over ground already covered. Unless you put all solutions thus far tried and failed into your question body, _with URL's if necessary_, your question will most certainly be off topic here.

Comment: you can use PendingFileRenameOperations:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc960241.aspx

Comment: @Compo I put all attempted solutions in **Attempted Solutions** also Isn't batch related to programing? If there are any other formatting errors/ways I can make the post better, please let me know and ill try and make the changes

Comment: @Sorceri How do you use it? The link doesn't tell me

Comment: @Ethan; No, because the issue lies with user error, not the script. We could possibly provide help to rewrite code so that it doesn't output to an invalid file name in the future but our remit isn't to fix the operating system issue you've now got.

Comment: @Compo I never had a problem with the script, it was deleting what the script created and I listed all the methods above we tried but none of them work

Comment: You could have googled it:  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager should be a multistring entry for PendingFileRenameOperations.  add value \??\<pathto file>

Comment: @Soceri I tried it and it didn't work, there was no PendingFileRenameOperations

Comment: @Ethan  then you just need to create it.  See here for a tool from Sysinternals: https://superuser.com/questions/58479/is-there-a-registry-key-to-tell-windows-to-delete-a-file-at-next-startup